# VLC for Android build failed in Ubuntu 16.04.2

Tags: android, linux, build, vlc, vlc-android

I try to build VLC for Android according to this manual: https://wiki.videolan.org/AndroidCompile/ but I have failed something. I newbie in Linux, so I don't understand what is going wrong.
I'm using latest Android SDK and NDK r14b (with latest r15b scrip failed too, but with a different error about can't find some .py script).

```
kage@kage-VirtualBox:~/Android/vlc/vlc-android$ ./compile.sh
*** No ANDROID_ABI defined architecture: using ARMv7
VLC source not found, cloning
Cloning into 'vlc'...
remote: Counting objects: 523700, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (99603/99603), done.
remote: Total 523700 (delta 426785), reused 517889 (delta 421819)
Receiving objects: 100% (523700/523700), 181.35 MiB | 2.75 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (426785/426785), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
Configuring
ABI:        armeabi-v7a
API:        9
PATH:       /home/kage/Android/vlc/vlc-android/toolchains/arm/bin:/home/kage/bin:/home/kage/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/kage/Android/Sdk/platform-tools:/home/kage/Android/Sdk/tools:/home/kage/Android/Sdk/platform-tools:/home/kage/Android/Sdk/tools:/home/kage/Android/Sdk/platform-tools:/home/kage/Android/Sdk/tools
EXTRA_CFLAGS:      -march=armv7-a -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mcpu=cortex-a8 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=softfp -MMD -MP -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -Wno-invalid-command-line-argument -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -no-canonical-prefixes -fno-integrated-as
VLC_CFLAGS:        -std=gnu11 -g -O2 -fstrict-aliasing -funsafe-math-optimizations
Building tools
yasm not found
To-be-built packages: yasm
/home/kage/Android/vlc/vlc-android/toolchains/arm/bin/make: 1: /home/kage/Android/vlc/vlc-android/toolchains/arm/bin/make: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
/home/kage/Android/vlc/vlc-android/toolchains/arm/bin/make: 1: /home/kage/Android/vlc/vlc-android/toolchains/arm/bin/make: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
buildsystem tools: make
```

but I have installed yasm:

```
kage@kage-VirtualBox:~/Android/vlc/vlc-android$ yasm --version
yasm 1.3.0
Compiled on May  6 2015.
Copyright (c) 2001-2014 Peter Johnson and other Yasm developers.
Run yasm --license for licensing overview and summary.
```

Help me with this issue, please!

Comment: Try `which yasm` to see if its on-path. If its not on-path, then maybe try `./compile.sh --help`. It may tell you to do something like `YASM=/path/to/yasm`.

Comment: Hi, the error does not seem to relate to yasm, it relate to `Syntax error: ")" unexpected` , not very informative, anyway I was able to compile with android-ndk-r13b

Comment: Hi! I resolved this issue with using Ubuntu x64 against Ubuntu x32 in VirtualBox. But I catch another problem with protobuf after 15 min of compile time. So I give up after several attempts. Need to try with ndk-r13b, I think.